# Calculating variables

Tags: powershell, variables

I am wanting to calculate variables.

For example:

```
$1 = 1
$2 = 2
$Sym = +
[int]$1 [int]$Sym [int]$2
```

As of right now I only get an error from trying to convert the symbol. Is there another way of doing this so I can still use a variable for the symbol? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable as an operator - Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672567/use-a-variable-as-an-operator-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-5.1) for this. It basically takes a string, executes it as if it were a command and outputs the result.

Also, keep in mind that your `+` needs to be in quote marks when assigning it to a variable, or else PowerShell will try to interpret it as an operator (and also don't try casting it as an int...).

```
$1 = 1
$2 = 2
$Sym = '+'

Invoke-Expression "$1 $Sym $2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it.